# Manipulate css animated position of element with JS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-transitions

sI'm trying to change the position of an element that is moved with a css animation on the x-axis. The goal is to move the element horizontally with the mouse clicked. The animation should of course continue to run regularly afterwards.

Important: just native js.

Any hints?

Basic example

```html
    <style>
    .dummyAnimation{width:100%;position:relative;height:100px;}
    .bump{width:100px;height:100px;background:blue;animation:dummySequence 30s linear infinite;position:absolute;}
    .bump:hover{animation-play-state:paused;}
    @keyframes dummySequence{
        0%{left:0;}
        100%{left:calc(100% - 100px)}
    }
</style>

<div class="dummyAnimation">
    <div class="bump"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying a bunch of things I came up with this 'hacky' thing, on `mousedown` remove the animation, on `mouseup` add the mouse position as a margin for offset, add the animation again.

```js
let cube =  document.querySelector('.bump')

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e)=>{
    cube.classList.remove('animation')
})

document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e)=>{
    cube.style = `margin-left: ${e.x - 50}px;`
    cube.classList.add('animation')
})
```

```css
    .dummyAnimation{width:200px;position:relative;height:100px;}
    .bump{width:100px;height:100px;background:blue;position:absolute;}
    .bump:hover{animation-play-state:paused;}
    .animation{animation:dummySequence 30s linear infinite;}
    @keyframes dummySequence{
        0%{left:0;}
        100%{left:100%}
    }
```

```html
<div class="dummyAnimation">
    <div class="bump animation"></div>
</div>
```

Ideally you'd want to get the mouse position and modify the `keyframes`
rule `left`, so the animation re starts from where you click, but from what I know there's no easy way to modify that. I guess you can just keep a copy of the style in js replace the entire `<style>` tag, with the modified value or something like that, but that seems "hackier" than this.

**Edit** - This makes it so the animation resumes from the point where the mouse was clicked to 100%, you can add checks to see if the position of the mouse exceeds the container width, so the cube doesn't get position outside of it, or attach the event on the container itself.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{

    let cube =  document.querySelector('.bump')
    let styleTag = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0]
    let initialStyle = styleTag.textContent
    
    let initialKeyFrame = " .animation{animation:dummySequence 3s linear infinite;display:block} @keyframes dummySequence{ 0%{left:0;}100%{left:calc(100% - 100px)}}"
    styleTag.textContent = styleTag.textContent += initialKeyFrame
    
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e)=>{
    cube.classList.remove('animation')
    })

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e)=>{
    initialKeyFrame = ` .animation{animation:dummySequence 3s linear infinite; display:block} @keyframes dummySequence{ 0%{left:${e.x-50}px;}100%{left:calc(100% - 100px)}}`
    styleTag.textContent = initialStyle
    styleTag.textContent = styleTag.textContent += initialKeyFrame
    cube.classList.add('animation')
    
    })

})
```

```css
    .dummyAnimation{width:400px;position:relative;height:100px;background:gray}
    .bump{width:100px;height:100px;background:blue;position:absolute;display:none}
    .bump:hover{animation-play-state:paused;}
```

```html
<div class="dummyAnimation">
    <div class="bump animation"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit 2** - Now the animation restarts from the beginning but I had to remove `.bump:hover{animation-play-state:paused;}` because it messes with the timeout.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{

    let cube =  document.querySelector('.bump')
    let styleTag = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0]
    let initialStyle = styleTag.textContent
    
    let initialKeyFrame = " .animation{animation:dummySequence 3s linear infinite;display:block} @keyframes dummySequence{ 0%{left:0;}100%{left:calc(100% - 100px)}}"
    styleTag.textContent = styleTag.textContent += initialKeyFrame
    
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e)=>{
    cube.classList.remove('animation')
    })

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e)=>{
    initialKeyFrame = ` .animation{animation:dummySequence 3s linear infinite; display:block} @keyframes dummySequence{ 0%{left:${e.x-50}px;}100%{left:calc(100% - 100px)}}`
    styleTag.textContent = initialStyle
    styleTag.textContent = styleTag.textContent += initialKeyFrame
    cube.classList.add('animation')
    setTimeout(()=>{
        cube.classList.remove('animation')
        initialKeyFrame = ` .animation{animation:dummySequence 3s linear infinite; display:block} @keyframes dummySequence{ 0%{left:0;}100%{left:calc(100% - 100px)}}`
        styleTag.textContent = initialStyle
        styleTag.textContent = styleTag.textContent += initialKeyFrame
        cube.classList.add('animation')
    }, 3000)
    })

})
```

```css
   .dummyAnimation{width:400px;position:relative;height:100px;background:gray}
    .bump{width:100px;height:100px;background:blue;position:absolute;display:none}
/*     .bump:hover{animation-play-state:paused;} */
```

```html
<div class="dummyAnimation">
    <div class="bump animation"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Something like that was also my first approach. However, in this way the whole area shifts and the animation itself continues, but the positions are no longer correct. For example, if I drag the box to the right during the animation, it continues to run the dragged length to the right over the edge. 

Of course, I want the animation to end at the right edge and not beyond it.

Comment: @Viewer I've added another approach, would this  be closer to the result you're looking for ?

Comment: Thats really close THX. 

But If you drag the element and this "animation-cycle" is over, it starts there where it was dragged. It would be nice, if it would start again at left:0 .

Comment: @Viewer How about now ? :)

Comment: @Viewer Ah, this breaks on multiple clicks.., it needs a debounce or something